# Python SQLite3 Problem with?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Im currently learning SQLite3 with Python. I'm looking at the manual, and it tells me to do something like the following:

```
data = (tablename, )
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ?(uid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT NOT NULL, duedate INTEGER NOT NULL, description TEXT, archived INTEGER)", data)
```

I'm getting an error, however. It's stated as follows:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sadly the DB-API’s parameter substitution `?` don't work with table name , columns name .. and it's the same in all DB API in python.

the DB-API’s parameter substitution just work for value like in `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?`, so you will have to do string formating or just put the name table in the string directly.

```
query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (uid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT NOT NULL, duedate INTEGER NOT NULL, description TEXT, archived INTEGER)" % table_name

conn.execute(query)
```

Comment: Thanks that solved it. I'm still in the php mysqli::stmt->prepare mindset